# Learning to use pandas datareader to plot Yahoo share price but it does not seem right

Tags: python, pandas, datareader

I'm learning with a O'Reilly course - Introduction to Pandas for Developers.

I plotted a chart using the Yahoo stock price. I have to modify the code given because it's out of date.

Here is the jupyter notebook: 
https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jeremy886/pydata-notes/blob/master/ipython-notebooks/Time_Series.ipynb

Please skip to the bottom for the chart.

I compared my chart with the author's and the history prices from Google and found mine is different from the others. (I think the author's is different from the Google's too).

Price Info from Google: https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=yahoo+price&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=vHJkWNPuKvOm8weq5qrQBw

At a glance, the pandas_datareader source seems not correct. For example, most of CLOSE prices I got are about $10. Like $12 for yesterday but the price from Google is about $38.

I wonder what is the problem?

- Is the pandas_datareader not trustworthy anymore
- Or there is some kind of adjustments I don't understand
- Or there is a bug in mine/author's code

Thanks and Happy New Year.

Comment: When I click on your google link I see the price for ticker YHOO (the company Yahoo), while your notebook shows data for stock F (Ford). The "yahoo" in your code is the data provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `data.DataReader('F', 'yahoo', start, end)`.

From the source:

```
def DataReader(name, data_source=None, start=None, end=None,
               retry_count=3, pause=0.001, session=None, access_key=None):
    """
    Imports data from a number of online sources.
    Currently supports Yahoo! Finance, Google Finance, St. Louis FED (FRED),
    Kenneth French's data library, and the SEC's EDGAR Index.
    Parameters
    ----------
    name : str or list of strs
        the name of the dataset. Some data sources (yahoo, google, fred) will
        accept a list of names.
    data_source: {str, None}
        the data source ("yahoo", "yahoo-actions", "yahoo-dividends",
        "google", "fred", "ff", or "edgar-index")
```

The first parameter is the name of the dataset you are interested in, in your case `'F'` for Ford.

The `data_source` parameter is the site that you are sourcing the data from. In your case, `'yahoo'`. This is not the same as the stock prices. If you look at Ford's stock price, you will see they compare well to yours.

When in doubt, read the docs. If the docs don't help, read the source - https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader

Comment: Thanks. I still can't find where it explains "F" is Ford. But this link ( https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/f ) shows Ford Motor's share price stats, so I assume "f" is from Yahoo. https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/f

Comment: Yes, the 'F' is from Yahoo. Replace it with whatever stock you are interested in, according to the code that Yahoo uses. You could put in 'AAPL' to get Apple's NASDAQ price data. Or whatever else the Yahoo API provides access to. `pandas-datareader` doesn't give you a list of the possible options for the `name` parameter because it would be **huge** and liable to change as new companies are added. Plus it may vary between data sources (i.e. Yahoo vs Google).